# Defining a series of facts in SWI-Prolog

Tags: prolog

Prolog newbie here;

I'm trying to define multiple facts at once, but I keep getting the error below:

```
?- assert(robin(damian, dick)).
true.

?- robin(damian).

ERROR: Undefined procedure: robin/1
ERROR:     However, there are definitions for:
ERROR:         robin/2
false.
```

The statements individually seem to work fine:

```
?- assert(robin(damian)).
true.

?- assert(robin(dick)).
true.

?- robin(damian).
true.
```

I'm not sure what the syntax error with the first line is, and I've tried changing it in many ways.

Thanks!

Comment: Well you define a predicate with two arguments, and you call a predicate with one argument. If you want to obtain `dick`. You should call it with `robin(damian,X)`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks you! You really cleared that up for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line you give is not defining multiple predicates at once, but is defining a single predicate with two arguments. When you then try to call it you are using a single argument, which is undefined as it says in the error message. This is also why it suggests `robin/2`. Calling it like `robin(damian, X)` will get rid of the syntax error by unifying the second argument with `X`, but based on your question it sounds like this is not what you want. You should probably just define the predicates one at a time if you would like to use them like you show in your second code sample.